# bash: list files that are not with a given extension

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering if there is a way to `ls` files in a folder that does not have a given extension? For example, if I have a folder full of `.cpp` and `.h` files, and I wanted to see if there are other types of files (such as config files and make files), how do I list or find?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls *!(.cpp|.h)
```

Comment: It doesn't show directories or files without extention...For example it doesn't show `test file` and `test dir` but it shows test.py for example..so this is not complete answer

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add a `-d` switch so that `ls` doesn't list the contents of matching subdirectories.

Comment: I like this answer because of its simplicity and the fact that other options of ls can be used on top of it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe through an appropriate `grep`, e.g.:

```
ls | grep -Ev '\.(cpp|h)$'
```